# charAt() Not Working

Tags: java, char

So, neither of these parameters are working. I try to compile it, and I get the same error message for both:

```
unexpected type
required: variable
found   : value

if(word.charAt(val) = guess)
              ^
```

The carat is pointing to the parentheses, however, so I'm not sure its an error with the parameter. I looked at about 15 sites, all of them saying that it should be an integer between 0 and 1 less than the length of word

```
int val = 0;
if(word.indexOf(guess) > 0 )
{
    if(word.charAt(val) = guess)
    {
        screentxt[val] = guess;
    }
    if(word.charAt(0) = guess)
    {
        screentxt[0] = guess;
    }   
}
```

Comment: chatAt is zero-based. Just so you know.

Comment: in your conditional statements, you're assigning, not comparing. use `==` instead of `=`. also, please include the full stacktrace and related code.

Comment: There is no callstack since it's a compiler error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are currently using assignments in your `if` expressions.

Use the `==` operator in your `if` statements to evaluate the `char` content:

```
if (word.charAt(val) == guess)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually attempting to do an assignment instead of a comparison:

```
if(word.charAt(val) = guess)
```

Change to

```
if(word.charAt(val) == guess)
```

In addition, you probably want to change:

```
if(word.indexOf(guess) > 0 )
```

to

```
if(word.indexOf(guess) >= 0 )
```

in the event that the `guess` char is actually the first char in `word`, in which case you can remove this since it's redundant:

```
if(word.charAt(0) == guess)
{
    screentxt[0] = guess;
}
```